# Faulty algorithm for simultaneous diagonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, eigenvector

I found a simple algorithm for simultaneous diagonalization of two commuting matrices ([Nordgren - Simultaneous Diagonalization and SVD of Commuting Matrices](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2006.16364)), which seemed to be well-founded. For commuting matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, this algorithm forms the Jordan decomposition of

$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{A},$$

then constructs

$$\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A}$$

and its Jordan decomposition,

$$\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{T} \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{T} \mathbf{S}^{-1}_\mathbf{T}.$$

The arXiv paper states that $\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{A} \mathbf{S}_\mathbf{T}$ satisfies

$$\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A} $$

and

$$\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{D}_\mathbf{B},$$

which would be favorable in terms of simultaneous diagonalization.

However, for specific $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ matrices (see below), I cannot retrieve the $\mathbf{D}_\mathbf{A}$ matrix from the $\mathbf{U}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{U}$ expression. Could you please help me what the problem would be with this algorithm? My Mathematica implementation is the following:

```
n = 5;
Q = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[1, {n, n}]];
a = {-3, -1, -1, 2, 3};
b = {-1, 1, 3, 3, 3};
A = Q . DiagonalMatrix[a] . Transpose[Q];
B = Q . DiagonalMatrix[b] . Transpose[Q];

{SA, DA} = JordanDecomposition[A];
T = Inverse[SA] . B . SA;
{ST, DT} = JordanDecomposition[T];
U = SA . ST;
Chop[N[FullSimplify[Inverse[U] . A . U], 5] // MatrixForm]
(* The output should be numerically equal to DA ~ DiagonalMatrix[a]. *)
```

Comment: Your $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$ do not commute (or, at least, pasting into `Mathematica` and asking `A.B==B.A` returns `False`).

Comment: Then try to form their difference A.B-B.A.

Comment: All matters Jordan decomposition are very ill conditioned, so round-off can matter quite a lot.  But actually I'm not sure what the issue is, because I am not used to using Mathematica for Jordan decompositions, and am not proficient enough at Mathematica code to tell at a glance what your code is doing.  When I run the code, it outputs something, so at least the code runs.  What should the output be, compared to what it is?

Comment: @LSpice I have been edited my question, posting a modified Mathematica code. So the essence of this implementation is the following: (a) form a **Q** random real orthogonal matrix, (b) construct two matrices **A** and **B** with predefined eigenvalues stored in vectors a and b, respectively, (c) execute the algorithm of the cited arXiv paper, and (d) print $\mathbf{U}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{U}$ which should be numerically diagonal, containing the entries of **a** as diagonal entries.

Comment: If I am not confusing things, $U^{-1}BU$ is $D_T$, not $D_B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the statement, which is probably that $U^{-1}AU$ and $U^{-1}BU$ are both Jordan, I guess with $U^{-1}AU=PD_A P^{-1}$ for some permutation matrix $P$ (since the Jordan form is unique only up to permutations of the Jordan blocks). That you are getting wrong nonzero non-diagonal elements of $U^{-1}AU$ is probably caused by numerical instability of some divisions.

I am not getting such wrong entries using `RandomInteger` instead of `RandomReal`:

[image]

We see that here $U^{-1}AU=PD_A P^{-1}$ for some permutation matrix $P$, indeed.

---

Here is another example, with a non-diagonal Jordan form for $A$:

[image]

We see that here, again, $U^{-1}AU=PD_A P^{-1}$ for some permutation matrix $P$.

Comment: Try to use the original a and b vectors. I think you will obtain incorrect results.

Comment: @TobiR : Done. The result is, of course, of the same kind.

Comment: Thanks. Then the problem was indeed around the orthogonalization and/or the Jordan decomposition.